# Cross-compiling with crosstool-ng and cmake: missing 3rd party libraries

Tags: linux, cmake, cross-compiling

I want to cross compile cmatrix app ([link](https://github.com/abishekvashok/cmatrix)) for raspberry pi, using crosstool-ng toolchain on desktop ubuntu. I am using cmake workflow for this, I created following cmake toolchain file based on [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/book/mastering-cmake/chapter/Cross%20Compiling%20With%20CMake.html):

```
# the name of the target operating system
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Linux)

# which compilers to use for C and C++
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER   aarch64-rpi4-linux-gnu-gcc)
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER aarch64-rpi4-linux-gnu-g++)

# where is the target environment located
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH  /workdir/crosstool-ng/x-tools/aarch64-rpi4-linux-gnu)

# adjust the default behavior of the FIND_XXX() commands:
# search programs in the host environment
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PROGRAM NEVER)

# search headers and libraries in the target environment
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY ONLY)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_INCLUDE ONLY)
```

Then, to compile I use:

```
mkdir build && cd build
cmake -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=../cross.cmake ..
```

This fails since cmake cannot find ncurses library:

```
-- Could NOT find Curses (missing: CURSES_LIBRARY CURSES_INCLUDE_PATH) 
-- Looking for use_default_colors
-- Looking for use_default_colors - not found
```

After that I tried “hacking” it by installing ncurses on target (RPi 4), copying .so files to the build machine from rootfs and trying to link it, but it resulted in more errors. Also this seemed like not the right way to go about it.

What is the correct workflow here? Basically, I have an application that uses external library (ncurses) and I want to cross compile it for another architecture.

Comment: Does **root directory** (`/`) of your target machine is accessible from the host machine? If yes, then just add the path to that directory to `CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH` variable, and CMake will be able to find things installed on the target machine. Otherwise, it is expected that every libary needed for your application will be **cross-compiled** on your host machine for the target one, and be installed using `make DESTDIR=/workdir/crosstool-ng/x-tools/aarch64-rpi4-linux-gnu` mechanism.